# Custom range for boost::range library

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, c++14, boost-range

I’m writing filter and map algorithms using boost::range library:

```
template <class Range> struct Converter
{
    Converter(const Range& p_range) : m_range(p_range) {}

    template<class OutContainer> operator OutContainer() const
    {
        return {m_range.begin(), m_range.end()};
    }

private:
    Range m_range;
};

template<class Range> Converter<Range> convert(const Range& p_range) { return {p_range}; }

template<class Range, class Fun> auto map(Range&& p_range, Fun&& p_fun)
{
    return convert(p_range | boost::adaptors::transformed(p_fun));
}

template<class Range, class Pred> auto filter(Range&& p_range, Pred&& p_pred)
{
    return convert(p_range | boost::adaptors::filtered(p_pred));
}
```

Right now I can use them like this:

```
std::vector<int> l_in  = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
std::vector<int> l_tmp_out = filter(l_in, [](int p){ return p < 4; });
std::vector<int> l_out = map(l_tmp_out, [](int p){ return p + 5; });
```

I would also like to write code this way:

```
map(filter(l_in, [](int p){ return p < 4; }), [](int p){ return p + 5; });
```

Unfortunately my Converter class does not compose with boost::range algorithms so this example does not compile. I'm looking for a proper way to change that.

**UPDATE**

I followed @sehe link and it turned out that all I had to do was to add this four lines to Converter class:

```
using iterator = typename Range::iterator;
using const_iterator = typename Range::const_iterator;
auto begin() const { return m_range.begin(); }
auto end() const { return m_range.end(); }
```

Comment: What's required is quite well documented here http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/extending.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my take on things:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e49ec9249a074c92)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/range.hpp>
#include <boost/range/adaptors.hpp>
#include <boost/range/algorithm.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

namespace MyRange {
    template <typename R> struct Proxy {
        Proxy(R&& r)      : _r(std::move(r)) {}
        Proxy(R const& r) : _r(r) {}

        template <typename OutContainer> operator OutContainer() const {
            return boost::copy_range<OutContainer>(_r);
        }

        using iterator       = typename boost::range_mutable_iterator<R>::type;
        using const_iterator = typename boost::range_const_iterator<R>::type;

        auto begin() const { return range_begin(_r); }
        auto end()   const { return range_end(_r);   }
        auto begin()       { return range_begin(_r); }
        auto end()         { return range_end(_r);   }

      private:
        R _r;
    };

    template <typename R> auto make_proxy(R&& r) { return Proxy<R>(std::forward<R>(r)); }

    template <typename Range, typename Fun> auto map(Range&& p_range, Fun&& p_fun) {
        return make_proxy(std::forward<Range>(p_range) | boost::adaptors::transformed(std::forward<Fun>(p_fun)));
    }

    template <typename Range, typename Pred> auto filter(Range&& p_range, Pred&& p_pred) {
        return make_proxy(std::forward<Range>(p_range) | boost::adaptors::filtered(std::forward<Pred>(p_pred)));
    }
}

int main() {
    using namespace MyRange;
    {
        std::vector<int> l_in  = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
        std::vector<int> l_tmp_out = filter(l_in, [](int p){ return p < 4; });
        std::vector<int> l_out = map(l_tmp_out, [](int p){ return p + 5; });

        boost::copy(l_out, std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout << "\nfirst:\t", "; "));
    }

    {
        boost::copy(
                map(
                    filter(
                        std::vector<int> { 1,2,3,4,5 },
                        [](int p){ return p < 4; }),
                    [](int p){ return p + 5; }),
                std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout << "\nsecond:\t", "; "));
    }
}
```

Prints

```
first:  6; 7; 8; 
second: 6; 7; 8;
```

#### NOTES

- it uses `std::forward<>` more accurately
- it uses const/non-const iterators
- it uses Boost Range traits (`range_mutable_iterator<>` etc.) instead of hardcoding assuming nested typedefs. This allows things to work with other ranges (e.g. `std::array<>` or even `int (&)[]`).
- the user-defined converson operator uses `boost::copy_range<>` for similar reasons

Comment: Should SFINAE that template conversion operator, no?

Comment: @Yakk What for? It'll just not compile when it doesn't compile.

Comment: Suppose you are calling a function and picking between two overloads, one of them takes an `int` the other a `std::vector<int>`.  You pass a range.  Your conversion operator claims that both are equally good, and the call is ambiguous.  With SFINAE support, the `int` case is discarded, and the correct overload is picked. Conversion should always be disabled when invalid, so make overloading work nicely: this applies both with conversion ctors and conversion operators. (I assume that `copy_range` works with a target of type `vector`, if not, replace `vector` with some range primitive.)

Comment: Compelling example. Yes, I suppose the OP could want that :). The whole point about using `copy_range` instead of blind uniform initialization (like the OP had originally) was indeed to prevent heinous things from happening unexpectedly :)

Comment: For situations like that I written explicit casting function `template<class OutContainer> OutContainer as() const { return boost::copy_range<OutContainer>(m_range); }`, but automatic solution would be preferred:). Any idea how it would look like?