# Creating a custom range class that wraps boost adaptors

Tags: c++, boost, c++17, c++20

I have a class that applies some boost transform adaptors to a range (for sake of example, in reality it's a lot more complex than this):

```
struct Foo {
    auto range() const {
        return boost::irange(0, 10)
            | boost::adaptors::transformed([] (auto x) { return x * 2; });
    }

    auto begin() const { return range().begin(); }
    auto end() const { return range().end(); }
};
```

This alone allows us to iterate over a `Foo` using a range for:

```
for (auto x : Foo()) {
    std::cout << num << std::endl;
}
```

However, this doesn't compose well with other boost adaptors or range operations (like `boost::join`):

```
auto bad = boost::join(boost::irange(0, 10), Foo());
auto also_bad = Foo() | boost::adaptors::transformed([] (auto x) { return x + 1; });
```

Both of the above provoke some nasty template errors. The former (`bad`):

```
In file included from test.cpp:4:
/usr/local/include/boost/range/join.hpp:30:70: error: no type named 'type' in
      'boost::range_iterator<const Foo, void>'
            BOOST_DEDUCED_TYPENAME range_iterator<SinglePassRange1>::type,
            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~
/usr/local/include/boost/range/join.hpp:44:28: note: in instantiation of template class
      'boost::range_detail::joined_type<const Foo, const boost::integer_range<int> >' requested
      here
    : public range_detail::joined_type<SinglePassRange1, SinglePassRange2>::type
                           ^
test.cpp:34:16: note: in instantiation of template class 'boost::range::joined_range<const Foo,
      const boost::integer_range<int> >' requested here
    auto bad = boost::join(Foo(), range);
               ^

...
```

And the latter (`also_bad`):

```
In file included from test.cpp:1:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/range/any_range.hpp:17:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/range/detail/any_iterator.hpp:22:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/range/detail/any_iterator_wrapper.hpp:16:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/range/concepts.hpp:24:
/usr/local/include/boost/range/value_type.hpp:26:70: error: no type named 'type' in
      'boost::range_iterator<Foo, void>'
    struct range_value : iterator_value< typename range_iterator<T>::type >
                                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~
/usr/local/include/boost/range/adaptor/replaced.hpp:109:40: note: in instantiation of template
      class 'boost::range_value<Foo>' requested here
                BOOST_DEDUCED_TYPENAME range_value<SinglePassRange>::type>& f )
                                       ^
test.cpp:35:27: note: while substituting deduced template arguments into function template
      'operator|' [with SinglePassRange = Foo]
    auto also_bad = Foo() | boost::adaptors::transformed([] (auto x) { return x * 2; });
                          ^
...
```

Both of the errors seem to be complaining that `Foo` isn't a range. I've tried adding an `operator OutContainer()` and typedefs for `iterator`/`const_iterator` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30469871/568785) to no avail. What must I do to `Foo` to allow it to play nicely with these range operations?

Comment: If you look at [the docs](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/utilities/join.html), it says that the range must model [*SinglePassRange*](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/range/doc/html/range/concepts/single_pass_range.html) (it helpfully gives a link). This concept description tells you everything your type needs. Also, see [*Extending the library*](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/extending.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is super helpful in this case. Your type has to model [`SinglePassRange`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/concepts/single_pass_range.html) and it does not. There's a [page](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/extending/method_1.html) about how to do this, and while you provided `begin()` and `end()`, you did not provide type aliases for `iterator` and `const_iterator`. Hence, you don't model `SinglePassRange`.

But it's actually quite good that your code failed, because it is also bad. You have `begin()` call `range().begin()` and `end()` call `range().end()`. Those are iterators into *different ranges*. So this is undefined behavior anyway - you're failing to meet the semantic concepts of a `SinglePassRange`.

The easier solution is to just use `Foo()` directly. This already works:

```
auto good = boost::join(boost::irange(0, 10), Foo().range());
auto also_good = Foo().range() | boost::adaptors::transformed([] (auto x) { return x + 1; });
```

And means you just have to write one function: `range()`

Comment: Thanks! I know this question sounded like I lazily hadn't read any docs. I had read that page, but didn't understand what from it was relevant to my issue. Providing a `range()` method was much simpler. Although, if I had chosen to go the route of making `Foo` range-able (if that's the right terminology). What would I have needed to return from `begin()` and `end()`? Why are `range().begin()` and `range().end()` iterators into different ranges? Would `auto r = range()` then `r.begin()` and `r.end()` have been more correct?

Comment: Further (sorry to pile on), if this is the case, why aren't ranges like iterators (where calls to `begin()` and `end()` are always compatible)? And although `SinglePassRange` is only defined with respect to `SinglePassIterator` (where the docs for this give only opsem), the following is still unclear to me: is it just named poorly, or would I only be able to iterate over a type modeling this once? It seems like the `begin()` iterator being copy constructible would allow me to keep it around (and then always use a new begin from which to start iterating).